# How to force variable to take a certain value depending on the value of another variable?

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I am working with python . I want to write a constraint that mathematically can be expressed as :
**x = 0 if y = 0**

I searched how to do that with ortools in python, but I am confused.
(maybe it has to do with this function OnlyEnforceIf https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/channeling , but I am not sure how the boolean would work here)

Answer (score 0):

With CP-SAT:

You need to create a Boolean var `b <=> y == 0`, then add the implication `b => x == 0`. This is shown in the examples listed in the channeling doc page.

Comment: can I do that with GLOP?

Comment: 1) With MIP solvers, you will need multiple big-M to code the implications. 2) GLOP is just a simplex, not a MIP solver, so it does not make sense.

Comment: I am sorry I meant , SCIP

Comment: Yes, look up big-M formulations for implications. You cannot use OnlyEnforceIf. And if your problem is purely integral, CP-SAT is usually faster.